# VBA Oauth parse html responsetext

Tags: html, vba, oauth, access-token

I am getting http response as HTML and I am trying to fetch the token from the response.
The response looks like the code below:

```
<title>Token</title>
<style>
input { white-space: nowrap; width: 500px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }
</style>
<div>
<input id="theToken" type="text" value="Bearer oaxgggfh12tpjhudhsbjj">
<button class="btn" onclick="copyToken()">Copy</button>
</div>
<div>
<label>(expires: 22.07.22, 21:18)</label>
</div>
<script>
function copyToken() { document.getElementById("theToken").select(); document.execCommand("copy"); }
</script>
```

Here I need the value of id "theToken". So far I managed to access div using

```
Set topics = html.getElementsByTagName("div")
```

But I cannot fetch the actual token string.

My oauth token request function looks like below:

```
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Set XMLHTTP_swlc = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    strurl = "https:***remoting/oauth-token?login=true"
    With XMLHTTP_swlc
    .Open "POST", strurl, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer" & "rlZ....PT0"
        .send
        
        ivari2 = .status
        Debug.Print ivari2
        
        
        html.Body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP_swlc.responseText
        Set tokn = html.getElementById("theToken").value
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `html.getElementById("theToken").value`

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for the comment. I have tried this but I get the error "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Where is HTML declared and populated?  Have you checked that `XMLHTTP_swlc.responseText` contains what you expect?  Would maybe help to update your post with the code you used for the call to `getElementById`

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams I have edited the code. Is this enough? Yes XMLHTTP_swlc.responseText contains what I expect in the id "theToken"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I copy and paste your provided HTML into a worksheet cell, and then run this:

```vb
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
html.body.innerHTML = [A1].Value   'your provided HTML fragment
Debug.Print html.getElementById("theToken").Value
```

...I get output `Bearer oaxgggfh12tpjhudhsbjj` as expected.  If you're not seeing that then maybe your `responseText` is not what you expect.